# how not to get an extra count in a while loop?

Tags: c, xcode, loops, counting, function-definition

I have the following code and every time i run it, I get an extra count. Say for example that I input 8 first round and then a 2 next round and exit with the sentinel -1, the sum will be 10 as expected, but the count will be 3. I've debugged the program and no matter if count comes before the scanf() or after, I still get a 3 value. One possible solution is to initialized count to -1. However, I feel I shouldn't have to and setting count equal to zero should work. Do I have to set count to -1?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculateAverage()
{
    int grade = 0, count, sum = 0;
    double average;
    
    count = 0;
    
    while(grade != -1)
    {
        
        sum += grade;
        count++;

        printf("input a grade: \n");
        scanf("%d", &grade);
        

    }
    
    average = (double)(sum)/(double)(count);
    printf("%.2lf", average);

    return;
}

int main( )
{
    while (1)
        calculateAverage();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first iteration of the loop always starts with a grade of 0 that is included in your count.  Take a look into `do-while` loops and see if you can figure out how that can help your algorithm.

Comment: Maybe start with `count = -1` instead of `count = 0`

Comment: read carefully your code ;) 
You enter your loop before starting inputting values with scanf . That means you'll have one additional iteration each time . 
if you are a beginner in programming , I suggest you make a trace of the variables in your algorithms , ie , take a pen and paper , follow your code , and update each variable . This way , you'll understand more what parts are not behaving as intended . 
Like @ChristianGibbons said , use a do-while loop

Comment: *"Do I have to set count to -1?"* - Is there any problem whatsoever with that?

Answer (score 1):

For starters there is no great sense to declare the variable `sum` as having the type `int` because in any case you are casting it to the type `double`

```
average = (double)(sum)/(double)(count);
```

You are increasing the variable `count` before the user will enter something.

The function can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculateAverage( void )
{
    const int Sentinel = -1;
    
    size_t count = 0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    
    printf( "input a grade (%d - stop): ", Sentinel );

    for ( int grade; scanf( "%d", &grade ) == 1 && grade != Sentinel; )
    {
        sum += grade;
        ++count;

        printf( "input a grade (%d - stop): ", Sentinel );
    }        

    double average = count == 0 ? sum  : sum / count;
    
    printf( "%.2lf", average );
}

int main(void) 
{
    calculateAverage();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
input a grade (-1 - stop): 1
input a grade (-1 - stop): 2
input a grade (-1 - stop): 3
input a grade (-1 - stop): 4
input a grade (-1 - stop): 5
input a grade (-1 - stop): 6
input a grade (-1 - stop): 7
input a grade (-1 - stop): 8
input a grade (-1 - stop): 9
input a grade (-1 - stop): 10
input a grade (-1 - stop): -1
5.50
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing count just before you enter -1. So, it counts -1 as well. Just in increase is if it's not -1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculateAverage()
{
    int grade = 0, count = 0, sum = 0;
    double average;

    while (grade != -1)
    {

        sum += grade;

        printf("input a grade (-1 - stop): ");
        scanf("%d", &grade);

        if (grade != -1) // Check this line
            count++;
    }

    average = (double)sum / count;
    printf("%.2lf\n", average, sum, count);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    while (1)
        calculateAverage();

    return 0;
}
```